# Authors in menu, template list post by author

Tags: posts, categories, author

Can i get a specific author in main menu and when you click on it to see all the post buy this author. Also i need to see all posts ordered by authors too in the menu. In what template should it build, because it is not a category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you can view posts by authors with a URL of the form `{home_url}/author/{author-slug}/`

If you'll be writing any PHP and need to output a link to an author's posts, see the function [get_author_posts_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url).

**Edit:** If you'll be writing your own author post page template, the filename should be one of the following formats: `author-{nicename}.php`, `author-{id}.php`, or `author.php`. The templates override in the order I listed them -- last one being the fallback.

Comment: ok but how can i put the author in the menu from the admin?

Comment: On the menu page, you can click on 'links' on the left side, and type in the url manually, then add it to the menu and save. -- If your username is George Georgiev, for instance, and your site is GeorgeGeorgiev.com, your link needs to be http://georgegeorgiev.com/author/george-georgiev/

Comment: i know about this functionality of wordpress, but i have think  for a way to choose authors more carefully not only typing them.

Comment: also it will need to link to a page where will only show the authors posts not the authors bio.

Comment: You will need a plugin to generate author page links automatically in the admin area. I do not think anyone has written a plugin with that feature. WordPress automatically filters to show only posts by an author when you are on the author archive page. If you only see a bio, your WordPress theme is choosing to not use that feature

Comment: Thanks that was what i need :) I will mark your answer like accepted with the comments! I will vote for your answers after 15 reputation :)

Comment: Thank you. Your question is good because I think linking to authors without programming or manually typing links is important. WordPress should add the feature.